# How do I find all commits that contain (not touch) a file in git?

Tags: git

In git, how do I work back from a branch head and find every commit that contains (not necessarily touches) a particular file please? The "touches" version is ok to write:

```
git log mybranch -- filename | grep "^commit" | awk '{print $2}'
```

For what I'm trying to do, though, namely building all of the revisions that contain a particular file (a `pom.xml`), this isn't enough. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't touch"? You want to find commits where the file was present, but not modified in anyway? Do you want to explicitly omit commits where the file was both present and modified?

Comment: @meagar: Exactly that, yes. I'm not interested in whether the `pom.xml` was modified in a particular revision, I'm only interested in whether I can run a Maven build for that revision (i.e. whether or not the `pom.xml` is actually present).

Comment: Quite interested to know the results actually. I think in the general case, you're basically looking for a way to find all commits meeting some arbitrary condition. You can wire something like this up with `git bisect` to find which commit *introduces* a change which meets a condition, but I've never had to simply list commits meeting some criteria.

Comment: `git log <mybranch> | grep "^commit" | awk '{print $2}'` can be replaced by `git rev-list <mybranch>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty bash solution. It fetches a list of all commit ids reachable from any branch, iterates over them, checking out each commit. If the file exists after checking out the commit, it prints out that commit id.

**This will destroy your working directory via `git checkout -f`**. Stash your changes before running it.

```
for x in `git log --all | grep -o "[a-z0-9]\{40\}"`
do
  git checkout -f $x &> /dev/null
  if [ -e "config/pom.xml" ]
  then
    echo $x
  fi  
done
```

Comment: Thanks :) I think I may have found a way to do it without checking out the different revisions in case it's of interest (see above), but I'm going to give you the answer anyway. Cheers!

Comment: @StuartGolodetz You should add your update as an answer, rather than editing it into your question.

Answer (score 6):

As another way of doing it, this seems to work without the need to check out the different revisions:

```
for REV in `git rev-list <mybranch>`
do
  HASPOM=`git ls-tree --name-only -r $REV | grep '<filename>'`
  echo "$REV $HASPOM" | awk 'NF==2{print $1}{}'
done
```